# Links fade in when hovered - how to get them to stay opaque when their target is visible?

Tags: jquery, css

On my page I have four links that show and hide a div each.  Take a look [here](http://new.element17.com/).

The markup for the links is as follows:

```
<li class="togglelink fadein button" data-block="albums" id="togglealbums">Albums</li>
<li class="togglelink fadein button" data-block="about" id="toggleabout">About Me</li>
<li class="togglelink fadein button" data-block="contact" id="togglecontact">Contact</li>
```

and

```
<img src="images/info.png" class="button nav_button fadein toggleinfo" id="info" alt="Show Info Pane" title="Show Info Pane">
```

The CSS for the `fadein` class is as follows:

```
.fadein {opacity:0.5; transition:opacity 0.5s; -webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s; -moz-transition:opacity 0.5s; -ms-transition:opacity 0.5s;}
.fadein:hover {opacity:1.0;}
```

And the jQuery that shows/hides the target divs is as follows:

```
$('.togglelink').on('click',function() {
  var id = $(this).data('block');
  $('#'+id).fadeToggle('slow').siblings('.toggleblock').fadeOut('fast');
});

$('.toggleinfo').click(function() {
  $('.info').fadeToggle('slow');
});
```

What I want to happen is that when the target div is open (`albums`, `about`, `contact`, and `info`, respectively) the link that targets it stays at `opacity: 1.0`.

I tried this:

```
$('.togglelink,.toggleinfo').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('fadein active');
});
```

Where the `active` class is:

```
.active {opacity: 1.0;}
```

But this had two issues: using the close buttons on the panes themselves won't cause the links to go back to semi-transparent, and, in the case of the top 3 links, clicking one link and then another will result in two fully opaque links.

The code for the close buttons is like this:

```
<img src="images/close_pane.png" class="togglelink fadein close_pane button" data-block="albums" alt="Close Album List" title="Close Album List">
```

How can I fix these issues?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.togglelink,.toggleinfo').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.active').toggleClass('fadein active');
    $(this).toggleClass('fadein active');
});

$('.close_pane').click(function(){
    $('li[data-block="'+ $('this').data('block') +'"]').removeClass('active').addClass('fadein');
});
```

Comment: Hm.  This is close, but it's not working with the close pane links, and for some reason now the close button for the info pane doesn't work at all...

Comment: Still no dice.  Same issues.

Comment: @NaOH Could you make a jsfiddle so I can figure out what's going on?

Comment: You can't look at the live site?

Comment: @NaOH No, it is very hard to debug on a live site, plus last time I checked I couldn't find the divs that are toggled by the links (clicking the links does nothing)

Comment: I think it's going to be too tough to create a jsfiddle as there's a lot of stuff going on on my site.  Can I give you access to the source, possibly?

Answer (score 1):

`var id = $(this).data('block');` should be `var id = $(this).attr('data-block');`

Also, can you remove the `fadein` class and just use jQuery's `fadeIn()`? jQuery's fadeIn() affects the inline style on the tag, which may be why it's not working.

```
$('.togglelink').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-block');
  $('#'+id).fadeToggle('slow');
  $(this).siblings().fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with the way it is now?  It works.  As for the first option, I can do it, but I'm not sure what the advantage is over CSS3 hover styling...